# The JAX-WS- annotation: @WebFault doesnt work after migrating from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java

Our company have Exceptions in a core-library, which is used by different systems. I can not change these core-Exceptions, because they are used everywhere, but I can extend from them.

A web-application needs to ask a specific system (a "Person-repository") for a Persons status, valid or not valid. The Person-repository throws PersonNotValidExceptions to the web-application for invalid persons. the method in the Person-repository is "getPerson" (see below).

In order to avoid a SOAPFaultException it is necessary to annotate the PersonNotValidException whith a @WebFault-annotation (I did not add any properties though). This worked in Java EE7 but unfortunately doesn't work anymore since my organization has migrated to Java EE8.

```
@WebFault
public class PersonNotValidException extends SbtpApplicationException     {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public PersonNotValidException(String string) {
    super(string);
}
}
```

The error message that first appears when running the web-client, immideately after the request to the Person-repository:

```
016-02-22 22:32:53,245 ERROR [http-/127.0.0.1:10080-1] [] [] [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: [ubuntu] [F098] PersonNotValidException: The person is not valid.: se.apotekensservice.personregister.exception.PersonNotValidExceptions: [ubuntu] [F098] PersonNotValidExceptions: The person is not valid
at se.apotekensservice.personregister.application.service.impl.PersonregisterServiceBean.getPerson(PersonregisterServiceBean.java:113)
j
```

Then I get this Stack-trace:

```
getPerson has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"cause"). Expected elements are <{}exceptionId>,<{}message> 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:910)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:711)

caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"cause"). Expected elements are <{}exceptionId>,<{}message>
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:664)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
```

And the Wicket-page (the client-application) gets a SOAPFaultException (which is obvious also when debugging)

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"cause"). Expected elements are <{}exceptionId>,<{}message> 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.getPerson(Unknown Source)
```

The interesting part might be why the Person-repository now generates all these Exception-parameters (compare the JEE 8 response with the JEE 7 response below).

The JAVA8 xml-response from the Person-repository that the client couldnt cope with was this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>[ubuntu] [4778] PersonNotValidException: The person is not valid </faultstring>
    <detail>
        <ns1:PersonNotValidException xmlns:ns1="http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister">
            <exceptionId xmlns:ns2="http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister">4778</exceptionId>
            <message xmlns:ns2="http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister">[ubuntu] [4778] PersonNotValidException: The person is not valid </message>
            <cause xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister" xsi:nil="true"/>
        </ns1:PersonNotValidException>
    </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

While the JAVA-7 xml-response (that worked) was this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>The person is not valid.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns1:PersonNotValidException xmlns:ns1="http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister"/>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The generated wsdl was this in JAVA8 (some of it at least):

```
<xs:element name="PersonNotValidException" type="tns:PersonNotValidException"/>
<xs:complexType name="PersonNotValidException">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exceptionId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

while the genrated wsdl was only this in JAVA7:

```
<xs:element name="PersonNotValidException" type="tns:PersonNotValidException"/>
<xs:complexType name="PersonNotValidException">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I have now solved the problem by adding a "cause" - element to the complex type, since the "cause" element probably was in an "unknown" namespace, i. e. I added this element to the Java-8 wsdl:

<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cause" type="xs:string">

Comment: The namespace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" of the JAVA8 xml-response from the Person-repository was not valid since the targetNamespace of the Java8 wsdl (in my example) was "http://se.apotekensservice/folk/personregister".